# Algorithm to find optimal pose of known polygon to cover a set of points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, point-in-polygon

I have the following problem: Given a set of points *S* in the plane and a known polygon *P*, find the optimal translation *(Δx,Δy)* and rotation *φ* such that *P* translated and rotated by this transform contains the maximal number of *s ⋲ S*.

I have found [one paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220991620_Optimal_Polygon_Placement) so far that seems to document two such algorithms.

But I would like to know if there are any others and/or known implementations of such algorithms.

Additionally, I could further constrain this question to rectangles of known size, would this make it easier somehow?

Comment: I know ICP, but I don't see how it helps here. The points are not on the contour necessarily, but contained.